# Java NIO. SocketChannel.read возвращает -1, когда Selector говорит, что чтение возможно

Tags: java, nio2

Использую java NIO c неблокирующими каналами.
код примерно такой:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        int num = selector.select();
        if (num == 0) {
            continue;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
    }

    Set keys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator it = keys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey)it.next();
        if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_READ) == SelectionKey.OP_READ) {
            MySocket mySocket = (MySocket)key.attachment();
            try{
                bytesReaded = mySocket.socketChannel.read(mySocket.readerBuffer);
            }catch (Exception ex){
            }
...
        }
        if ((key.readyOps() & SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) == SelectionKey.OP_WRITE) {
            MySocket mySocket = (MySocket)key.attachment();
            mySocket.socketChannel.write(writeByteBuffer);
            key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        }
    }
```

После того, как я записал что-то в сокет и переключился на режим чтения, мне Selector говорит, что канал готов к чтению, но я постоянно получаю на нём -1 прочитано байт. (В целом это правильно, так как на другом конце сокет закрыл соединение), но как мне отловить эту ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, ключ стоит проверять на валидность

```
if (!key.isValid()) continue;
```

Во-вторых, проверку на готовность к чтению надо делать так

```
if (key.isReadable())
```

В-третьих, наличие в канале EOF - это тоже готовность к чтению.

Наконец, надо удалять обработанные ключи из итератора и закрывать каналы со своей стороны, чтобы они больше не появлялись в цикле событий.

Comment: Оба запроса отвечают true. Я пытаюсь сделать keep-alive соединения. Т.е. после записи в сокет я жду, что оттуда поступят данные. Если на той стороне соединение ещё держится, то всё хорошо, но если оно закрылось (а там обычный сокет применяет команду socket.close()), то у меня появляется готовность к чтению, но приходит всегда -1. При этом key.isValid()==true, key.isReadable()==true, socketChannel.isConnected()==true.Получается вопрос - как мне узнать, что соединение пропало?

Comment: `if (channel.read(buffer) == -1) channel.close()` или `key.cancel()`